# Easiest Way to Create SourceFile of Any Kind

Tags: windows

I'm used to create source code via 'make new .txt' and modify its extension. And this is not great and kinda annoying for using both keyboard and mouse...

Q. so, Is there any way to create source file than that?

Comment: Just create `new.c` instead of `new.txt`?

Comment: what tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a program that creates and opens an empty file, like this:

```
cd yourpath
type nul > new.c
Notepad "main.c"
```

Replace `yourpath` with the path where you intend to store your file to.

Save this file named to something like **createfile.bat**. Drag & Drop it to your favored place and then you can double-click it to create your file and open it. The problem you will face at the second use is that the file's name is unchanged. So, you will need to somehow make your filename unique, like adding a timestamp to its end or the like.

Answer (score 0):

[Extending the New Submenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context#extending-the-new-submenu).

Assuming you already have .c files associated with a text editor you can just import this .reg file into the registry:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.c\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my way to make source code! by using shellscript..

1. open file manager
2. right click at dir to open terminal
3. use 'ni commands' of shell

It's a easy way to create and modify any file!